# Retrieve icon from vb.net project

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have an existing vb.net project (vb.net 2010). There is a form in the project that has an icon; I want to get that icon so I can use it in another form I am adding to the same project. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can do it in code, it is as simple as putting the following line in `Form2`'s `Load` event:

`Form2.Icon = Form1.Icon`.

-

However, if you are trying to get icon into your designer, it's a little more work.

First, you need to get the `Form1` icon saved to a file.  Then you can use the designer's icon selector to choose it.

Here is the code you need to run inside of `Form1` to save it to a file:

```
   Using writeStream As Stream = File.Create("C:\temp\tmpIcon.ico")
      Me.Icon.Save(writeStream)
    End Using
```

You can create a temporary button on `Form1` and put the above code into the button's Click event handler.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. The latter is what I was looking for, but that first might be a better solution for me.